# Inlining SVG files in html using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, svg, webpack

Im building a web app, using `.svg`'s for icons. For some time I've been using this loader: https://github.com/appedemic/inline-svg-loader to inline my svgs in my HTML, but it seems like much of a hack, and it doesn't work when using the minifying.

I've now spend hours to try to come up with a fix. Essentially what I want is for this:

```
<button>
  <svg src="../../assets/icons/music_note.svg">
</button>
```

To turn into this:

```
<button>
  <svg>...</svg>
</button>
```

Now syntax doesn't have to be this way, of course, but do you know of any loaders or solutions to this problem?